# Extract month from date in Apache Superset SQL Lab Query

Tags: mysql, jinja2, apache-superset

I have a MySQL database in the backend of an Apache Superset installation, and I am trying to create a table where each row aggregates some counts by month, given a datetime column. I am able to use the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses successfully using Jinja templating, but `SELECT` does not work:

```
SELECT client_id, COUNT(DISTINCT file_name) AS n_files, status, '{{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}' AS 'month'
FROM `Table`
WHERE received_date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
AND received_date < '2022-09-30 00:00:00.000000'
GROUP BY client_id, status, '{{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}'
ORDER BY client_id, '{{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}', status
```

Ideally this query's result should be something like:

```
client_id | n_files | status | month
-------------------------------------
1         |   10    | Pass   | January 2022
1         |   5     | Fail   | January 2022
2         |   42    | Pass   | January 2022
2         |   12    | Fail   | January 2022
1         |   30    | Pass   | February 2022
1         |   8     | Fail   | February 2022
2         |   96    | Pass   | February 2022
2         |   7     | Fail   | February 2022
...
```

But instead I am getting:

```
client_id | n_files | status | month
-------------------------------------
1         |   10    | Pass   | {{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}
1         |   5     | Fail   | {{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}
2         |   42    | Pass   | {{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}
2         |   12    | Fail   | {{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}
1         |   30    | Pass   | {{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}
1         |   8     | Fail   | {{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}
2         |   96    | Pass   | {{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}
2         |   7     | Fail   | {{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}
...
```

Unfortunately this flavor of MySQL on Superset does not support something like `MONTH(received_date)` which would make it easier, but I am not sure what am I doing wrong with the Jinja templating of the datetime column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) instead because `strftime` is used in **sqlite** only
so you could edit it like this

```
SELECT client_id, COUNT(DISTINCT file_name) AS n_files, status, DATE_FORMAT(received_date, '%M %Y') AS 'month'
FROM `Table`
WHERE received_date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
AND received_date < '2022-09-30 00:00:00.000000'
GROUP BY client_id, status, '{{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}'
ORDER BY client_id, '{{ received_date.strftime("%B %Y") }}', status
```